# Unable to Import Connectors

Tags: wso2-esb

I am using Eclipse Luna.
I am trying to import some WSO2 connectors in my ESB Config project.
On the Add Connectors pop up I choose 'Connector Store Location' and then input the URL 'https://store.wso2.com'.
Upon clicking 'Connect' no connectors load.

Abhay.

Comment: A negetive vote for what? I tried searching for similar questions but could not find one.

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse Mars is the recommended one to create the ESB config projects. One more thing, you don't need to input the store URL anymore because when you click the Connector Store Location then it shows the default URL. When you click the connect button it fetches all the connectors and show.

you can refer the following links,

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Installing+WSO2+ESB+Tooling

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Working+with+Connectors+via+WSO2+ESB+Tooling

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try and let you know.